# TypeError: Cannot read property 'leafletElement' of undefined, React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

:)
I have a little problem here, and would appreciate any help since i cannot find the problem myself. I built a map with React-Leaflet, where i render certain points inside a bound box.

```
        <Map
            style={{ zIndex: 1 }}
            maxZoom={19}
            viewport={viewPort}
            onViewportChanged={onViewportChanged}
            ref={mapRef}
            className="markercluster-map"
          >
            <TileLayer
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
              attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            />
            <ClusterGroup clusteredData={clusteredData} setZoom={setViewPort} />
          </Map>
```

I get the bounds with this function:

```
const onViewportChanged = (viewport) => {
    const b = mapRef.current.leafletElement.getBounds();
    setBounds([
      b.getSouthWest().lng,
      b.getSouthWest().lat,
      b.getNorthEast().lng,
      b.getNorthEast().lat,
    ]);
    console.log(bounds)
  };
```

This functions very well, and i am able to send the bounds to my backend so i can fetch the markers. However, i created another map as a child where i wanna render another set of markers as a heatmap.

```
...Map component from above is Parent..

<HeatMap onViewportChanged={onViewportChanged2} ref={mapRef2} />

... some more code...
```

The code from the HeatMap component:

```
    <Map
        style={{ zIndex: 1 }}
        maxZoom={19}
        className="markercluster-map"
        viewport={viewPort}
        onViewportChanged={onViewportChanged}
        ref={ref}
      >
        <HeatmapLayer
          fitBoundsOnLoad
          fitBoundsOnUpdate
          gradient={{
            0.1: first,
            0.2: second,
            0.4: third,
            0.6: fourth,
            0.8: fifth,
            "1.0": sixth,
          }}
          points={addressPoints}
          longitudeExtractor={(m) => m[1]}
          latitudeExtractor={(m) => m[0]}
          intensityExtractor={(m) => parseFloat(m[2])}
        />
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
      </Map>
```

Now i passed viewPortChanged2 and mapRef2 from the parent as props. And when i render the HeatMap component with this function:

```
  const onViewportChanged2 = (viewport) => {
    const b = mapRef2.current.leafletElement.getBounds();
    setBounds([
      b.getSouthWest().lng,
      b.getSouthWest().lat,
      b.getNorthEast().lng,
      b.getNorthEast().lat,
    ]);
    console.log(bounds)
  };
```

It throws me this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'leafletElement'  of undefined

I dont know what causes it..

Comment: Can you make a demo to repdroce the issue?

Comment: const b = mapRef2.current.leafletElement && mapRef2.current.leafletElement.getBounds();